# How to change all caption to single spacing and not have reference turn up after every chapter

Tags: spacing, cross-referencing, lyx

I've two questions when using LyX:

1. How to change all caption to single spacing?
   I've tried to insert these into the LaTeX preample but they don't work due to some error message.

   ```
   \usepackage{caption}
   \captionsetup{font={stretch=1}}
   ```
2. As I have several child document that I wanted to put together, the reference will turn up at the end of every chapter. How can I let the reference only turn up at the end of everything without having to temporarily delete away the reference for outputting the PDF? I need them there as I will sometimes still output each child document to see individually.

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this problem. I need the main body of the whole paper to be double spacing and the caption to be single spacing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about `font=\singlespacing`?

Comment: `\captionsetup{font={stretch=1}}` is somehow redundant. The option `stretch=` is only available when using the `setspace` package additionally, but when using the `setspace` package the `caption` package will do the captions single spaced automatically. So the main question is: How does Lyx double spacing? As long as we don't know we can't answer the first part of your question in a proper way.

Comment: I tried to add this in the latex preamble
 \captionsetup{font=\singlespacing} 

But I was given the following error message
                                       
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: I'm actually not quite sure how the stretch works. I just found this solution from some other questions that is also trying to amend the spacing of the captions. I've changed the whole paper to double spacing by Document>Settings>Text Layout>Line Spacing>Double. It automatically converts everything into double spacing including the caption.

Comment: Alternatively, can someone please guide me how to instruct LyX to make the main body double spacing and caption single spacing? I'm currently using the Document Class as book (Memoir).

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour of captions is to be set in single spacing, even if you set the document layout to be spaced double in LyX's `book (Memoir)` document class:

[image]

This yields as output a single-spaced caption with a double-spaced body text:

[image]

The [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) [user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) does mention this about using the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption):

> **10.13 THE CLASS VERSUS THE CAPTION PACKAGE (AND ITS FRIENDS)**
>
> For some, the configurations for captions provided by the class, are either a bit too complicated or not complicated enough.
>
> The `caption` package by Alex Sommerfeldt may provide a simpler and much more extensive
>   configuration interface for captions. The package can be used with the class, but
>   there are a few caveats:
>
> (a) All of the special configuration macros provided by the class will no longer have any
>   effect (`caption` overwrites the core, and thus our interfaces will have no effect),
>   (b) `\abovecaptionskip` will be reset to 10 pt, and `\belowcaptionskip` to zero. (The
>   class would set both to `0.5\onelineskip`, so if you need to change these, move the
>   change until after `caption` has been loaded)